# User defined hierarchy in cube (dyslexia)

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, dimension

I can make 6 level dimension hierarchy with such relationships:

1. main -> lvl1
2. lvl1 -> lvl2
3. lvl2 -> lvl3
4. lvl3 -> lvl4
5. lvl4 -> lvl5

Hierarchy looks fine in the dimension browser.
All attribute keys are composition keys of each other.

When i try to use dimension in cube, with main as key to measures, it will fail citing:
'Attribute key 'main' not found..'

In the measures are all members of the dimension hierarchy.

is the relationship faulty or what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really tricky area of SSAS. The quickest way forward is probably to install BIDS Helper and use the "Dimension Health Check" function:

http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dimension%20Health%20Check&referringTitle=Documentation

It will show you all the issues in your data (not just the first one which you have discovered so far) and give you some info on how to proceed.

Personally I've gone off building attribute relationships due to the difficulty of debugging and fixing these issues. I tend to build dimensions now where every attribute relates directly to the key attribute. You never see these errors and performance seems very similar. You can still present the users with hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

When one defines compound keys in dimension, one must provide value column which corresponds the measures key column.